# Creation of .m2 folder after deletion while working in eclipse

Tags: maven

I am working on my first project on maven in Eclipse IDE and encountered an error that says following

> "could not resolve repository"

then I was instructed to delete `.m2 folder` and build it again.

How do I build it again ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `.m2` folder contains a folder `repository` and a `setttings.xml` (if you created one). The `repository` contains cached artifacts from the remote repositories and your own built artifacts. If you don't need the artifacts you have build any more, you can savely delete the folder `repository`. This might help you resolve problems with broken cache.